# How does Cassandra store null values?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

How does Cassandra store null values internally? Does it take up any storage space at all? I'm writing an application that uses a table with many many columns (100s) to represent varying types of data, so the columns have names like "text1", "text2", "number1", "number2", etc. and then there is an external JSON schema that maps what column represents what value for a specific data type. So, it could be for a certain data type that many columns have null values, and I have not been able to find anything concrete regarding the storage space (if any) that would be taken up by the null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't actually specify the name of the column and value `null`, it won't consume any space. E.g.

```
row1 col1 col4
     val1 val4

row2 col1 col2 col4
     val1 val2 val4

row3 col3 col4
     val3 val4
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! So leaving it out completely is the way to go. If I do specify it, but with a null value, then does it become a "Tombstone" and therefore take up some small space?

Comment: Not too sure about tombstones, but usually `null` is a pointer to 0, and pointers still take space. On a separate note, I'd be cautious about your schema in JSON file - such approach isn't standard. Also, try thinking about _all_ your queries upfront. Queries aren't usually easy to change in Cassandra.

Comment: Inserting a null value for a column DOES create a tombstone, so you should avoid inserting null columns all costs.  C* 2.2 introduces 'unset' which might be away around this.   Depending on your driver there are ways to use unset, usually if you have a bind marker ('?') in your query and you don't bind anything there, with 2.2+ it won't insert a tombstone: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/2.2/nodejs-driver/reference/nullUnsetValues.html